# Нет работает запрос с групировкой

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос, который должен сгруппировать данные из базы по дате

```
 SELECT 
 `Date`, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(`nick` SEPARATOR ' ') `nicks`
    FROM `test`
    GROUP BY 
     `Date`
```

Но он не группирует. Почему?

Comment: `Date` какой тип?

Comment: @Total_Pusher - datetime

Comment: что такое "не работает", он либо должен что то вернуть (при наличии данных) либо выдать сообщение об ошибке, по которому обычно понятно в чем проблема

Comment: Но группировать нужно только по дням, не учитывая Часы минуты секунды.

Comment: раз не учитывая, так и группируйте только по `date(\`Date\`)`

Comment: `datetime` - это с временем. У вас скорее всего не нужно учитывать время. Используйте конструкцию [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html): CAST(Date AS DATE)

Comment: @Mike , он не группирует. Данные выводит, например сегодняшний день выводит столько раз сколько он записан в базе

Comment: @Total_Pusher  можете для примера на моем запросе набросать?

Comment: выводите `date(\`Date\`)` (а не само поле с временем) и `group by date(\`Date\`)`

Comment: @Mike помогло, спасибо!)

Comment: SELECT CAST(`Date` AS DATE), GROUP_CONCAT(`nick` SEPARATOR ' ') `nicks` FROM `test` GROUP BY CAST(`Date` AS DATE)